# Session Preview service - 403 Forbidden

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, session-preview, dxa-java

I have installed the DXA 1.3 Java Version in Tomcat.

I have also installed the Session Preview Service in Tomcat. I have verified that the service is working as per the instructions by hitting http://localhost:8080/cd_preview_webservice/ws/odata.svc

However, when I try to use Update Preview in Experience Manager I see the following error:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service. The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I see an IPV6 address in the locahost Tomcat access log:

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [01/Mar/2016:15:23:18 +0000] "POST /cd_preview_webservice/ws/odata.svc/$batch HTTP/1.1" 403 496

I have tried adding a hostname for the service but that made no difference.

I have added the following url to my Session Preview Pub Target: http://localhost:8080/cd_preview_webservice/ws/odata.svc
I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: How did you configure your Publication Target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cd_ambient_conf.xml for the preview webservice was missing the preview cartridge.

Adding

```
 <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
```

Fixed the issue.